# How to write Cases in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to write a query where I have two schemas `vai_public` and `snow_public`. I need to select ID, and custom_fields from anyone of the schemas.  I have to write a case statement if my `&{schema}` = `vai_public` I need to retrieve  `custom_fields` which is a json column

```
{
  "assignee_email": “vai@gmail.com”,
  "assignment_group_value": "b0841caedb447014e8932282ca9619b9",
  "case_label_list": "false"
}
```

if my schema is `snow_public` I have to retrieve the `custom_fields` which is a json column

```
{
 "manager_name": "Terli,
  "origin": "Portal",
  "priority_support_c": false,
}
```

This is the sample query i have tried but i'm not aware how to approach my problem.

```
SELECT
    cs.id,
    (
        SELECT
            CASE 
        WHEN &{schema} = ‘vai_public’ THEN 
            parse_json(cs.custom_fields):assignee_email::STRING as assignee_email,
            parse_json(cs.custom_fields):assignment_group_value::STRING as assignment_group_value,
            parse_json(cs.custom_fields):case_label_list::STRING as case_label_list
                WHEN &{schema} = ‘snow_public’ THEN 
                    parse_json(cs.custom_fields):manager_name::STRING AS manager_name,
                    parse_json(cs.custom_fields):origin::STRING AS origin,
                    parse_json(cs.custom_fields):priority_support_c::STRING AS priority_support_c,
            END
        FROM (SELECT 1) 
    ) 
FROM
    vaibhav_database.&{schema}.my_table AS cs;
```

Comment: You can't do that - that's not how (standard) SQL works. Use dynamic SQL to create the statement that you want to execute and then execute it

Comment: Thanks for commenting @NickW. Could you please provide me with any references for Dyanamic sql statements which i can look into for my problem.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index